# Laravel: validation in store method

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a `ConferencesController` with `store` method. In my view, I POST to `conferences.store` and I do my validation logic and `Redirect::to` in the `store` method.

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Conference::$rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Er ging iets mis, zie de errors hieronder.')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {
        $conference = new Conference();
        $conference->title = Input::get('title');
        $conference->description = Input::get('description');
        $conference->location = Input::get('location');
        $conference->plannedTime = Input::get('plannedTime');
        $conference->save();
    }
}
```

The validation might fail, or not, but the controller does not do the `Redirect::to`, is this a known problem? How do I solve it?

Comment: just add `return` b4 the redirect , everything in laravel work through the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Er ging iets mis, zie de errors hieronder')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```